# Is there a strictly positive function with strictly negative derivatives?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Are there any functions $f(x)>0\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$, such that, assuming $f$ can be differentiated with respect to $x$, its derivative $f'(x)<0\ \forall x\in \mathbb{R}$?

If such functions exist, how can they be constructed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $e^{-x}$.

Or more generally, $e^{g(x)}$ where $g'(x) < 0$.